# using spread operator in class methods vs functions

Tags: javascript, typescript, spread-syntax

I'll try to keep this succinct:

I have this static class method

```
private render(fruit1, fruit2, fruit2){
  console.log(a,b,c)
}
```

which called by `setTable1` using normal function declaration works.

```
public setTable1 = function(data) {
 this.render(...data); // spread operator works with func syntax
}

setTable1(['apple','banana','orange']);
```

However, `setTable2` does NOT work when using method syntax

```
public setTable2(data) {
 this.render(...data);
}
```

UNLESS....I change `setTable2`to this:

```
public setTable2(data) {
  this.render.apply(null, ...data)
}
```

What is it about the difference between method vs function syntax that causes the spread operator to fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first case works because you initialize `setTable1` at runtime and because you have not set the type of it, it is `any` (compiler does not know that it is a function with some parameters), and compiler can not detect any errors on that until runtime. Runtime works correct because it is just a Javascript.

Your issue with the second case is related to the arguments match. Compiler can not detect how many values have `...data`, maybe `2` or `1` which may not match to the arguments count. For this it throws error that the *arguments does not match*. As a workaround you can use default values for the parameters and code will work.

```
private render(fruit1 = '', fruit2 = '', fruit3 = '') {
  console.log(fruit1, fruit2, fruit3)
}
```